# Use UUID version 1 or 4 for iCloud clientId

Tags: api, icloud, uuid

In all of the examples I've been able to find with people using the iCloud API, they seem to set the `clientId` by generating a random UUIDv1 and making it uppercase (usually).

I also understand that UUIDv1 and UUIDv4 differ in that UUIDv1 won't generate collisions because it's based on MAC address and timestamp.

Would it then be bad to use UUIDv4 for this iCloud `clidentId`?